# BufferedImage imageType in swing

Tags: java, swing, scala, java-2d

I'm writing a widget that does some caching to avoid unecessary calls to Shape.draw on a bunch of shapes at every repaint.

I've tried to do something like this (scala code):

```
private val buffer = new BufferedImage(width, height, /* (1) */)
...
override def paintComponent(Graphics2D g) = {
  if (hasChanged) {
     val bg = buffer.getGraphics.asInstanceOf[Graphics2D]
     bg.draw(/* ... */)
     buffer.flush
  }
  g.drawImage(buffer, null /* (2) */, 0, 0)
}
```

I'm not sure what to put in `(1)` and `(2)`. `null` for (2) seems to work (I want no transformation). But for `(1)` I have no idea which image type to chose. Is there a way of asking for the "right" one at runtime?

Comment: depends - do you need the buffered image to be transparent? if not, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB might be okay.
You may also want to create a "compatible" image instead. See 'BufferedImage img = g.getDeviceConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(
        width, height, Transparency.OPAQUE);'
where g is an instance of Graphics2D

Comment: I've tried different images types, among them TYPE_INT_RGB, but I get at best a black and white image. With a CompatibleImage, I get a black image.
[EDIT] With TYPE_INT_ARGB I get a colorful image, but will that be the same on every platform?

Comment: It works with `createCompatibleImage` too, but "setBackground" didn't paint the background so I thought it was black, thanks!

Comment: I don't want to be nitpicky, but it should read

`override def paintComponent(g: Graphics2D) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tedil pointed out, `g.getDeviceConfiguration().createCompatibleImage( width, height, Transparency.OPAQUE)` does the trick.